# how to return non-zero value in a multiple results with two criterias

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
date        shift   product
8/17/2018   2nd     0
8/17/2018   2nd     0
8/17/2018   2nd     0
8/17/2018   2nd     OH4
8/17/2018   2nd     0
8/17/2018   2nd     0
8/18/2018   2nd     0
8/18/2018   2nd     2
8/18/2018   2nd     0
8/18/2018   2nd     0
```

see example above, find the first non-zero 'product' value that has a specified date and shift number? such as 8/17/2018 and shift 2nd, and get result "OH4".

how to write formula with index and match?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the first non-zero 'product' value that has a specified date and shift number? If so, please edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: edit to clarify question.

Comment: When you run into multi-criteria problems like this, a simple way to solve it is to add a helper column that you use to do the multi-criteria logic and return a true/false (1/0) result for each row.  Then you can do a simple VLOOKUP on the helper column.  Rajesh S's solution does this without a helper column by using an array formula, which evaluates all of the rows at once (a little more abstract, but powerful once you learn it).  So you've got two approaches for when you run into this kind of problem again.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Write this array formula in Cell `B8` and confirm it by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` (Excel will add curly braces around it to indicate that it is an array formula):

```
=INDEX(C$2:C$5,MATCH(1,(A$2:A$5=A7)*(B$2:B$5=A8)*(C2:C5<>0),0))
```

*In this example, target date is in A7 and target shift is in A8.  Adjust cell references in formula as needed.*

MATCH looks for a result of TRUE (i.e., `1`) where a row will match the target date in column A, target shift in column B, and non-zero value in column C.  Each test will return a value of `1` if true or `0` if false, so the product of the tests is `1` only if all three tests are true.